# Detach listener realtime listener using modular SDK: "Property 'off' does not exist on type ' DatabaseReference'."

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm migrating my Realtime database implementation from Namespaced to Modular. In Modular I have the following working correctly:

```
const reference = firebase.database().ref(`/projects/${uuid}`);
reference.off();
```

I have rewritten this to:

```
const reference = ref(firebase, `/projects/${uuid}`);
reference.off();
```

According to the docs, detaching listeners works the same (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners). So I would expect `reference.off()` to still work, also in the modular version.

However, it gives the error:

> Property 'off' does not exist on type ' DatabaseReference'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation for [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.databasereference), there are no methods at all on the object. That's what the error message is telling you.

Instead, you can use the [off()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#off) function. Be sure to read that carefully so you can match the event type with the one you used with whatever `on*()` function you used.

```
off(ref, 'your_matching_event_type');
```